Docker build: npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine
Im building an image based on mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/python:0-3.11-bullseye
I have the following at the end of my docker file:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest
#RUN npm install -g typescript

RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

IM seeing this at the end of the build:
#13 [ 9/12] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs npm
#13 CACHED

#14 [10/12] RUN npm install npm@latest -g &&     npm install n -g &&     n latest
#14 0.793 npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
#14 0.793 npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'npm@10.7.0',
#14 0.794 npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0' },
#14 0.795 npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.12', npm: '7.5.2' }
#14 0.796 npm WARN EBADENGINE }
#14 2.626
#14 2.626 added 1 package, and audited 209 packages in 2s
#14 2.626
#14 2.626 24 packages are looking for funding
#14 2.626   run `npm fund` for details
#14 2.627
#14 2.627 found 0 vulnerabilities
#14 3.639
#14 3.639 added 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 890ms
#14 3.640
#14 3.640 found 0 vulnerabilities
#14 3.813   installing : node-v22.1.0
#14 3.898        mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/22.1.0
#14 3.901        fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v22.1.0/node-v22.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
#14 7.582      copying : node/22.1.0
#14 8.766    installed : v22.1.0 (with npm 10.7.0)
#14 8.766
#14 8.766 Note: the node command changed location and the old location may be remembered in your current shell.
#14 8.766          old : /usr/bin/node
#14 8.766          new : /usr/local/bin/node
#14 8.766 If "node --version" shows the old version then start a new shell, or reset the location hash with:
#14 8.766 hash -r  (for bash, zsh, ash, dash, and ksh)
#14 8.766 rehash   (for csh and tcsh)
#14 DONE 8.9s

#15 [11/12] RUN node --version
#15 0.399 v22.1.0
#15 DONE 0.4s

#16 [12/12] RUN npm --version
#16 0.712 10.7.0
#16 DONE 0.7s

It's not clear to me how to solve this or whether its an issue, as it does appear the newer versions are installed.
Ive seen several stackoverflow posts on how to install npm/node, have tried many of them, but i cant seem to get rid of those WARN lines.
Is this something to be concerned with? if so, what is the proper way of solving this
EDIT: after posting this, i noticed the CACHED line after the initial install of nodejs and npm.  Building with --no-cache options doesnt seem to help

You won't be able to install npm latest on node 12 (which is what appears to be what your base container is coming with) maybe do npm install npm@6 instead. When you install node 20 using n it should install a newer npm as well. I would however suggest you install node 20 directly rather than via n

@apokryfos thanks.  what's interesting, is once i get into the container, the versions do see to the be latest. so im guessing because of the base image, the warning happens when trying to npm install npm@latest -q, but later n is able to install latest node and latest npm

The following would bypass the out-of-date node version implied by your image being frozen-in-time, so instead of falling back on the distro's old version of node, run this...
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_22.x | bash - &&\
apt-get install -y nodejs

Read more about your options at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions?tab=readme-ov-file#debian-versions
Commands running after that install command should then be using a modern node. I wouldn't bother installing the distro version of node at any time - it's main job is to have MS tools and have the right python.

thanks - i have seen similar recommendations.  this seems reliant on knowing the latest version. is there an option to this that will pull and install the latest?

If you use https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x you will get the LTS version and if you use https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x you will get Current.
